# Adicionar uma string a uma variavel

Tags: html, html5

Tenho o seguinte código  para uma capo de usuario:

```
<input id="DomainUserName" name="DomainUserName" type="text" class="textInputField" runat="server" size="25" autocomplete="off" />
```

Dessa forma o usuário é obrigado a digitar dominio@usuario ou dominio/usuario , quero que não seja necessário digitar o domínio , que a varial receba o usuario e insira o dominio sozinho.

Comment: Essa variável será criada em qual linguagem de programação? Pode completar a sua pergunta adicionando essa informação? Dessa forma a comunidade poderá te ajudar.

Comment: O domínio é variado?

Comment: Marcus Vinicius Duarte Pinheir seja bem-vindo a comunidade, te recomendo a fazer o [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender como funciona a comunidade, primeiramente tente fazer algo, depois faça a pergunta expondo sua dúvida e ou problema, da uma olha o que é [dentro do escopo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), (problemas de programação em si).